# Problems when collapsing Treeview nodes in VB.net

Tags: treeview, vb.net-2010

I’m having trouble with TreeView when opening a form from clicking on a child node, then closing that form (the FormClosed event does have Me.Close() and Me.Dispose() in it). The problem accrues after collapsing the parent node, the previous form opens again.
The form is open from Treeview AfterSelect event.

```
    Private Sub TreeView1_AfterSelect(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.AfterSelect
    Dim rc%, i%

    Dim daFoodCat As New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * FROM tblFoodCategories INNER JOIN tblRecipes " & _
                                          "ON tblFoodCategories.RecipeID = tblRecipes.RecipeID " & _
                                          "ORDER BY RecipeName", cn)
    Dim dsRecipeName As DataSet = New DataSet
    daFoodCat.Fill(dsRecipeName, "tblFoodCategories")
    rc = dsRecipeName.Tables(0).Rows.Count

    For i = 0 To rc - 1
        If dsRecipeName.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("RecipeName") = e.Node.Text Then
            rcpID = dsRecipeName.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("tblRecipes.RecipeID")
        End If
    Next

    If rcpID = 0 Then
        'Do nothing
    Else
        frmRecipes.ShowDialog()
    End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by adding rcpID = 0 after frmRecipes.ShowDialog().